# How to get timeseries of CPU usage from Prometheus api

Tags: prometheus

I have a Prometheus running in Kubernetes that monitors deployment of my app. I can see the cpu usage and other metrics as time series on http://localhost:8080/. But how can I get that time series from Prometheus API? I only found endpoint that returns list of avaible metrics, but not the data itself. Is there a way to simply get CPU usage from Prometheus API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [query API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) for that.

Basically (assuming Prometheus is running at localhost:8080) `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/query_range?query=node_cpu_seconds_total&start=2022-09-07T00:00:00Z&end=2022-09-07T02:00:00Z&step=5m`, which returns your data in a JSON document.

Comment: The `/api/v1/query_range` doesn't return raw samples stored in Prometheus. It returns **calculated** samples at the requested timestamps `start`, `start+step`, `start+2*step`, ..., `end`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for details.

Comment: very interesting @valyala, but the requirement for raw data wasn't in the original question and query_range is the usual way for visualization purposes - still upvoted your answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus returns raw samples for the given [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) on the time range `(time-d .. time]` when querying [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries). The `d` is the lookbehind window specified in square brackets after the time series selector. For example, the following command returns raw samples for time series with the name `node_cpu_seconds_total` on the time range `(2022-09-07T00:00:00Z .. 2022-09-08T00:00:00Z]`:

```
curl http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/query?query=node_cpu_seconds_total[1d]&time=2022-09-08T00:00:00Z | jq .
```

Pay attention that the `query` param must be properly encoded with [url encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Otherwise the query may return unexpected results.

See also [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639).